# When nth element in array is updated, 0th element is also updated inside custom adapter Android studio. How to resolve this

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio

Array functions: When I update nth element in an array in `custom adapter`, it is updating nth element also moving the nth value to zero position. Ex: `Array[0,0,0,2,3,0,0]` if i update 3rd position with value 5 it should be `Array[0,0,0,5,3,0,0]` but i is becoming `Array[2,0,0,5,3,0,0]` . So ideally it is moving old value of nth position to 0th position.

Any idea why this is happening? Below is the sample code. When i update in category Hair, for 11th or 12th position for more than one time 0th position is updated with previous value. But 0th position should be updated only when category is Beauty.

```
 if(categoryPassed == "Beauty"){

  qtyBeauty[position] = qtyBeauty[position] + 1;
}

else if(categoryPassed == "Hair"){

  qtyBeauty[position + 10] = qtyBeauty[position + 10] + 1;
}
```

Comment: Remember to add a language tag like Android / Java. Most of us who are trying to help filter questions using some language tags.

Comment: Added code blocks

Comment: Added the tags. Thanks

Comment: `categoryPassed.equals("Beauty")` not `==`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. Array was getting updated in a different loop. Found the solution now. Thanks